# Excluding a subdomain from RewriteCond

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm running a Zend Framework (PHP) application on Apache. As you might know, this framework requires all URLs to be routed to `public/index.php` (front controller pattern). Therefore, i've added the following rules to the `.htaccess` in the `public_html` directory:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]

# rewrite non-www url's
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

In DirectAdmin, I've created a subdomain called `newsletter`, which (by default i guess) expects its files to reside in `public_html/newsletter`. However, when i visit `newsletter.mydomain.com/somefile.html` the `.htaccess` rules redirect this to `http://www.newsletter.mydomain.com//public/newsletter/`.

How can I exclude my subdomain from the `.htaccess` rules ?

Comment: Not changing anything...

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteEngine On

# don't apply any rewrites to the domain newsletter.mydomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^newsletter\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule .* - [L]

# rewrite non-www url's
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#shouldn't be needed!
RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
```